# Is there a Material component for global error messaging?

Tags: material-design, material-components

In the Material Design patterns documentation, there is a section in Errors called "Incompatible values" (you have to scroll down to it).

https://material.google.com/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors

This section shows an example form and how to present an error. At the top of the form is a grey panel with an error message in it, in addition to the field-level error messages. However, there is no mention of a component to use in order to produce this kind of message.

Is this just some custom element or is there a Material component to produce this kind of message?

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no specific Material-UI component for that.